# Converting Stream into IntStream

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am setting the id for each list item where primary address for two list are equal.

Server POJO

```
public class Server {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    public Integer id;


    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "server",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<IPAddress> ipaddresses;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setIpaddresses(List<IPAddress> ipaddresses) {
        this.ipaddresses = ipaddresses;
    }

    public List<IPAddress> getIpaddresses() {
        return ipaddresses;
    }
}
```

IPAddress POJO

```
public class IPAddress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="ipaddress")
    private String ipaddress;

    @Column(name="primaryIP")
    private boolean primary;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "server_id")
    private Server server;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIpaddress() {
        return ipaddress;
    }

    public void setIpaddress(String ipaddress) {
        this.ipaddress = ipaddress;
    }

    public boolean isPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
    }

    public Server getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }


}
```

Here is my logic for replacing duplicates.

**Note:** currServerList is a list from db and importServerList which I am importing servers into db therefore importServerList will not have id when I replace currServerList I want to update the server(replace with importServerList) rather having duplicates.

```
Set<String> primaryIpAddresses = importServerList.stream()
                    .map(Server::getPrimaryIpAddress)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

            Set<Integer> currServerId = currServerList.stream()
                    .filter(s->primaryIpAddresses.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
                    .map(Server::getId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

            List<Server> filteredList=currServerList.stream()
                    .filter(s->!primaryIpAddresses.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            filteredList.addAll(importServerList);
            filteredList.stream().filter(s->primaryIpAddresses.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress())).forEach(s->s.setId(currServerList.stream().filter(server->currServerId.contains(server.getId())).mapToInt(Server::getId)));
```

> This is my logic but how do I convert this Stream to IntStream I tried
>   but not working
>   **filteredList.stream().filter(s->primaryIpAddresses.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress())).forEach(s->s.setId(currServerList.stream().filter(server->currServerId.contains(server.getId())).mapToInt(Server::getId)));**
>   **Compiler Error:** The method setId(Integer) in the type Server is not applicable for the arguments (IntStream)

Still will not work because I am not setting the id where it is equal

**UPDATED:**

```
filteredList.stream().filter(s->currListPrimaryIpAddress.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
            .forEach(srv -> srv.setId(currServerList.stream().filter(server->primaryIpAddresses.contains(server.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
            .findFirst()
            .get().getId()));
```

Previous code in the answer was setting the same id for all servers but I tried without functional programming using simple for-each loop like this

```
for(Server srv : filteredList) {
                for(Server dbsrv : currServerList) {
                    logger.debug("dbsrv ipadd --> " + dbsrv.getPrimaryIpAddress());
                    logger.debug("impsrv ipadd --> " + srv.getPrimaryIpAddress());
                    if(dbsrv.getPrimaryIpAddress()!= null && dbsrv.getPrimaryIpAddress().equals(srv.getPrimaryIpAddress())) {
                        srv.setId(dbsrv.getId());
                        logger.debug("in setting server id");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now checking null was necessary since it was throwing exception at that line since there are some data in db which is wrong therefore I am sort of doing **Defensive coding** but now I need to write the same above code using functional programming.

Comment: Not sure about this line `IntStream.currServerList.stream().` does this possible?

Comment: @manfromnowhere not working when I used like that.....and you got my problem ?

Comment: when I replaced servers from currServerList based on servers which have primary ipaddress equal to importServerList then I need to set the id of that replaced servers of currServerList into the importServerList

Comment: There is function called `mapToInt` may be you should try that way . what you are doing is totally wrong . No such thing there in `Stream`

Comment: @manfromnowhere not working since I have List<Server> not List<Integer> and see my above comment

Comment: Let say You have  `List<Server>` and try to convert `IntStream` why can't you do like `yourlistName.stream().mapToInt(Server::getId);` ?

Comment: @manfromnowhere Ok I did your part into my code also I updated mine code also since earlier wasn't correct since I don't want to set the id anywhere rather only to places where I have primary ipaddress equal in both list

Comment: where is the method `Server::getPrimaryIpAddress`?

Comment: @Plootus I don't have ide with me right now .i can't check it . You may check with below answer

Answer (score 1):

change

```
s->s.setId(currServerList
         .stream()
         .filter(server->currServerId.contains(server.getId()))
         .mapToInt(Server::getId)
```

to

```
s->s.setId(currServerList.stream()
         .filter(server->currServerId.contains(server.getId()))
         .mapToInt(Server::getId)
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(0)
```

The answer is with the assumption that if `.filter(server->currServerId.contains(server.getId()))` doesn't match anything, let it return 0 for default condition.

You can change that to what suits your for default value.

Comment: findFirst().get().getId()) is this okay to your corresponding code ?

Comment: Yeah but it can throw exception if the value is not present. If you are OK with it, you can go that way also

Comment: You can remove the redundancy of doing two `getId` calls per element by changing the order: `.map(Server::getId).filter(currServerId::contains).findFirst().ifPresent(s::setId)`. Since the source data is an `Integer` and the target method receives an `Integer`, using an `IntStream` here causes an unnecessary boxing operation at the end. So you can use just `map` instead of `mapToInt`.

Comment: @Holger I have updated my problem please look at the last

Comment: Simply how to write the equivalent code using functional programming in the above case