# Setting id with stream java 8

Tags: java-8, functional-programming

I have Server POJO and I am giving you the details of this POJO and related one in the link below

[POJO structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925103/converting-stream-into-intstream)

I am setting the id for each server based on condition when **primaryipaddress** are same but problem in **db** is that some server might *not have primary ip* address.

I wrote a simple for-each to resolve it but I need to write it with using **functional programming**

```
for(Server srv : filteredList) {
                for(Server dbsrv : currServerList) {
                    logger.debug("dbsrv ipadd --> " + dbsrv.getPrimaryIpAddress());
                    logger.debug("impsrv ipadd --> " + srv.getPrimaryIpAddress());
                    if(dbsrv.getPrimaryIpAddress()!= null && dbsrv.getPrimaryIpAddress().equals(srv.getPrimaryIpAddress())) {
                        srv.setId(dbsrv.getId());
                        logger.debug("in setting server id");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried this way but same id was set on each server

```
 filteredList.stream().filter(s->currListPrimaryIpAddress.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
                .forEach(srv -> srv.setId(currServerList.stream().filter(server->primaryIpAddresses.contains(server.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
                .findFirst()
                .get().getId()));
```

I just want the equivalent functional code for above simple for-each and then my problem will be solved

Comment: what are `currListPrimaryIpAddress` and `primaryIpAddresses` and how are they related to the original code (the code without streams)?

Comment: @Eran currListPrimaryIpAddress are primary addresses from servers stored in database and primaryIpAddresses are the primary addresses whose servers I am updating but if there is a conflict like two servers having same primary ip address then I want to update servers on same id therefore getting id from currServerlist and setting in corresponding server id of filteredList

Comment: Though I given the link also you can look

Comment: @Eran I think we could use Optional....have you found anything?

Comment: What are you doing in foreach and stream is diferrent logic. Can you write the foreach with out stream to what you want?

Comment: @Rohit I already wrote please look at the foreach that is exactly I want using functional programming

Comment: @Rohit look at the first part

Answer (score 0):

Then it is very simple:

```
filteredList.stream()//
    .forEach(srv -> srv.setId(currServerList.stream() //
        .filter(dbsrv -> dbsrv.getPrimaryIpAddress() != null && dbsrv.getPrimaryIpAddress().equals(srv.getPrimaryIpAddress()))//
        .findFirst().map(f -> f.getId()).orElse(null)) //
);
```

If no currentServer Ip matches the dbServer ip(the filter is never true for currentServer), then the findfirst will result is empty optional then we set `null` for Ip.

Comment: I am getting exception using this code it says "no value present" when catching and displaying at the UI using e.getmessage()

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present .....in stack trace I am getting this

Comment: Then no dbserver primary address with matching current server primary address

Comment: no in this case I have all current server primary address inside the dbserver.....its actually current server is a subset of dbserver in my case but not necessary that current server has all the server of dbserver......and if not present then it should not give exception bro

Comment: Rohit any solution you found yet?

Comment: See the update to answer. `NoSuchElementException` means findFirst results in empty optional, which means filter returns false for one of the currentServer ips

Comment: I am saying it's possible to have no matching of primary address for one or more servers since there are some dummy servers but haven't put ip address for those server therefore I need to prevent it